# ACF Plugin WP with list-group - Vimeo

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, list

I Would like integrate variables of WP ACF plugin in list group but I don't know how start...
Somebody could help me please.

My code :

```
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
     <iframe id="vimeo-player-1" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/186190015?api=1&player_id=vimeo-player-1&amp;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;playbar=0&amp;loop=1&amp" frameborder="0" data-progress="true" data-seek="true" data-bounce="false" data-title="Planification" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>



    <div class="list-group">






<a href="#" data-id="vimeo-player-1" data-seek="00.0" class="timecode list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa fa-play-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Introduction<span class="badge">0:24</span></a>

<a href="#" data-id="vimeo-player-1" data-seek="24.0" class="timecode list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa fa-play-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> PIC & Plan d’approvisionnement<span class="badge">0:52</span></a>
<a href="#" data-id="vimeo-player-1" data-seek="76.0" class="timecode list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa fa-play-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> PDP<span class="badge">0:17</span></a>
<a href="#" data-id="vimeo-player-1" data-seek="131.0" class="timecode list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa fa-play-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Plan de charges<span class="badge">0:55</span></a>  
<a href="#" data-id="vimeo-player-1" data-seek="159.00" class="timecode list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa fa-play-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> L’ordonnancement<span class="badge">0:28</span></a> 
<a href="#" data-id="vimeo-player-1" data-seek="177.0" class="timecode list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa fa-play-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Autres fonctionnalités Planification<span class="badge">0:18</span></a> 
    </div>


</div>
```

For vimeo url it's ok. 
But It's doesn't work with list group.

I need a version pro with repeater fonction ? 
Thank you. 
Ju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is right ?

```
<?php if(get_field('yo')): ?>

    <div class="list-group">

<?php while(has_sub_field('yo')): ?>

<a href="#" data-id="vimeo-player-1" data-seek="<?php the_sub_field('dataseek_meta'); ?>" class="timecode list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa fa-play-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php the_sub_field('seek_name'); ?><span class="badge"><?php the_sub_field('dataseek'); ?></span></a>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Unlike a traditional forum, this section is for answers to the original question only. If you would like to add more information or code to your question please use the [`edit` link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/244295/edit) found directly below your question.